# Git Blame see changes after a certain date

Tags: git

Using [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame), is it possible to see only changes made after a certain date on a file?

I am trying to run,  *git blame* on a file with over 10000 lines and a large commit history. Its hard to spot only recent changes using *git blame*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Read the [Specifying Ranges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#_specifying_ranges) section of the git-blame manual.  Specifically, you're interested in the `--since` option:

> When you are not interested in changes older than [...] 3 weeks [for the file `foo`], you can use revision range specifiers similar to [git rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list):
>
> ```
> git blame --since=3.weeks -- foo
> ```
>
> When revision range specifiers are used to limit the annotation, lines that have not changed since the range boundary ([...] the most recent commit that is more than 3 weeks old in the above example) are blamed for that range boundary commit.

So essentially any line that was modified before the time you specify will begin with a `^` character, because that is the marker for the range boundary.

You can then use `grep` to filter out lines beginning with `^`:

```
git blame --since=3.weeks -- foo | grep -v '^\^'
```

Comment: The "You can then use grep to filter out lines beginning with ^: `git blame --since=3.weeks -- foo | grep -v '^\^'" ` is a great finale! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[git blame --since=`<date>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)